# Why I can't solve these equations using some specific parameters? (Sympy)

Tags: python, sympy, equation, equation-solving

Here's the code with equations I'm trying to solve using `sympy`:

```
# Import sympy
from math import remainder, tau
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers import solve

# Define the parameters
nx, ny, nz = [0,0,1]
a,b,c = [0,0,0]
d = 1
t = 9

# Solve the equations
theta = remainder(2*t*sqrt(b**2+c**2+d**2), tau)
delta, beta, gamma = symbols('delta beta gamma')
beta = 7 # Randomly assigned. 
eq1 = Eq(tan((delta+beta)/2),nz*tan(theta/2))
eq2 = Eq(ny*tan((delta-beta)/2),nx)
eq3 = Eq(cos((delta+beta)/2)*cos(gamma/2),cos(theta/2))
result = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [delta, beta, gamma])
```

My question is based on the last parameter `t`. For the current value, the function should be solvable but it doesn't return any results. If I change the value of t to some other values, then I can get the result. For instance, if `t=99`, then the results look like

```
[(-12.0619298297468, 9.00000000000000, 7.46580816699663e-8*I), 
(-12.0619298297468, 9.00000000000000, 12.5663706143592 - 7.46580045560101e-8*I)]
```

Why I'm unable to get the result from the first t value? How can I fix the issue? Thanks!!

Comment: What is `ny` in your example?

Comment: It's better if you post a single complete piece of code to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin Sorry I had a typo in my original code, just fixed

Comment: You create `beta` as a `symbol` but then replace with a number.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the comment! In my current setting `beta` has to be specified to make `delta` meaningful.

Comment: If `nx` and `ny` are both zero then the second equation is `0=0` so you've really only got two equations for 3 unknowns

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin Yeah so I assigned `beta = 9`:)

Comment: `beta` and `eq2` don't do anything with these values.  How about making `theta` a symbol, get the `result`, and then evaluate with a specific numeric values (via `.subs`)?

Comment: Wait are you asking to solve for `9` as one of the unknowns?

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin I'm asking if I could obtain the solutions of `[delta, beta, gamma]` if I set `t=9`:) In my jupyter notebook that doesn't work.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, what do you mean by 'evaluate with a specific numeric values'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 In [59]: 
    ...: delta, gamma = symbols('delta gamma')
    ...: theta = symbols('theta')
    ...: beta = 9
    ...: eq1 = Eq(tan((delta+beta)/2),nz*tan(theta/2))
    ...: #eq2 = Eq(ny*tan((delta-beta)/2),nx)
    ...: eq3 = Eq(cos((delta+beta)/2)*cos(gamma/2),cos(theta/2))
In [60]: eq1
Out[60]: 
   ⎛δ   9⎞      ⎛θ⎞
tan⎜─ + ─⎟ = tan⎜─⎟
   ⎝2   2⎠      ⎝2⎠
In [61]: eq3
Out[61]: 
   ⎛γ⎞    ⎛δ   9⎞      ⎛θ⎞
cos⎜─⎟⋅cos⎜─ + ─⎟ = cos⎜─⎟
   ⎝2⎠    ⎝2   2⎠      ⎝2⎠
In [62]: result = solve([eq1, eq3], [delta, gamma])
In [63]: result
Out[63]: 
⎡⎛                            ⎛       ____________       ⎞      ⎞  ⎛                          ⎛       
⎢⎜      ⎛   ⎛θ⎞⎞              ⎜      ╱     1          ⎛θ⎞⎟      ⎟  ⎜      ⎛   ⎛θ⎞⎞            ⎜      ╱
⎢⎜2⋅atan⎜tan⎜─⎟⎟ - 9, - 2⋅acos⎜√2⋅  ╱  ────────── ⋅cos⎜─⎟⎟ + 4⋅π⎟, ⎜2⋅atan⎜tan⎜─⎟⎟ - 9, 2⋅acos⎜√2⋅  ╱ 
⎣⎝      ⎝   ⎝2⎠⎠              ⎝   ╲╱   cos(θ) + 1     ⎝2⎠⎠      ⎠  ⎝      ⎝   ⎝2⎠⎠            ⎝   ╲╱  

____________       ⎞⎞⎤
     1          ⎛θ⎞⎟⎟⎥
 ────────── ⋅cos⎜─⎟⎟⎟⎥
 cos(θ) + 1     ⎝2⎠⎠⎠⎦
```

Now evaluate some of the `result` terms with specific `theta` values.

```
In [64]: result[0][0].subs({theta:-0.849})
Out[64]: -9.84900000000000
In [65]: result[0][1].subs({theta:-0.849})
Out[65]: -2⋅acos(0.707106781186547⋅√2) + 4⋅π
```

I don't see any clues as to why `result` would be empty (no solution) for certain values of `t`, and hence `theta`.  But it should be easier to explore those issues with this algebraic solution.

```
In [66]: t=9
In [67]: remainder(2*t*sqrt(b**2+c**2+d**2), tau)
Out[67]: -0.8495559215387587
```

That `acos` term might be the problem:

```
acos(0.707106781186547⋅√2)
```

That's approximately `acos(1)`, but `nan` if the `acos` arg is at all larger than 1.

With `numpy`:

```
In [299]: def foo(theta):
     ...:     return np.sqrt(2)*np.sqrt(1/(np.cos(theta)+1))*np.cos(theta/2)
     ...: 
In [300]: foo(0)
Out[300]: 1.0000000000000002
In [301]: foo(-1)
Out[301]: 1.0000000000000002
In [302]: foo(-.89)
Out[302]: 1.0000000000000002
In [303]: foo(-3.0)
Out[303]: 0.999999999999998
```

So the `acos` argument is algebraically 1, but numerically may be a bit larger, resulting in a `nan`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! That's super helpful:)